# Is it possible to load XML document with DOMElements case-folded?

Tags: php

I'm loading an XML document with [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/domdocument)'s [loadXML function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php). There doesn't appear to be any [options](http://us.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) to case fold DOMElement's tagName and attribute names.

I need to treat the XML document as being case-insensitive so this should be considered invalid (name and NAME should be the same, not unique):

```
<input name="field" NAME="field2" />
```

Likewise the getAttribute/setAttribute functions should treat "NAME" AND "name" as the same attribute.

The [xml parser functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) appear to have this functionality through the [xml_parser_set_option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parser-set-option.php) function through the "XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING" constant. But DOMDocument and these functions appear to be mutually exclusive, with the only similarity being they both use libxml2 behind the scenes.

So is there any way to force DOMDocument to case-fold? Are there any drop in replacements that use the xml parser functions? I'm looking to avoid using anything that uses regular expressions. The appeal of DOMDocument is the object vs procedural design.

Normally the XML document nodes should be lowercase anyway. But I'd like my code to still work if someone capitalizes something and transform it to lowercase after parsing the document.

Comment: Hm, XSLT could do it think. I see a try at [this url](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200612/post30020.html)

Comment: I did some experimenting with XSLT. It does work, but it striped out my CDATA tags and encoded the text inside. It also stripped out my DOCTYPE. I'm sure there's probably a way to make it work, but it seemed to mess with the original document more than DOMDocument does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific function to ignore case (or de-dupe attributes) in the DomDocument class, but you could just lower the case of the relevant XML parts before you load it in to get some of the way there?

```
function xml_case_fold($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace_callback('#(</?[^!><= ]+)([^><]*>)|(<!\[CDATA\[)(.*\]\]>)#si',
        function($tag)
        {
            if($tag[1])
            {
                $tag[2] = preg_replace_callback('#([^><= ]+)(=(["\']).*?\3)#s',
                        function($attr)
                        {
                            return strtolower($attr[1]) . $attr[2];
                        }, $tag[2]);

                return strtolower($tag[1]) . $tag[2];
            }
            else
            {
                return $tag[0];
            }
        }, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a step in the right direction. How would I not touch text inside a CDATA element?

Comment: Added a couple of characters. Hopefully will ignore the CDATA tag. I don't really work with XML though - if you point me to a typical file I'll check it for you.

Comment: Heed usual warning about manipulating XML with regex. Tony the pony etc etc

Comment: Paul: I mean something like <script><![CDATA[var test = "<B></B>";]></script> where the <B>'s should not be touched because they reside in a CDATA block. Not sure if RegEx will work for this. cbuckley: Any alternative strategies? I don't like having to use RegEx either.

Comment: I've made it so all CDATA is stripped and then re-added (hopefully untouched). If you have another neater method I would suggest that too!

Comment: It works. Not as neat as you mentioned. Would prefer a non-regex solution though. But if not, seems to be my only option.

Comment: It should be easy enough to implement as a temporary measure at least until one of the site uber-boffins comes along with the 'right' answer... Good luck!

Comment: After some work I found a way to do it with just 2 preg_replace_callback functions. I still want to give you credit. Is it OK if I edit your answer with the revised code?

Comment: Edit away, the whole point of the site is to help others looking for a specific solution...

Comment: I ended up going with this. XSLT "worked", but screwed up my CDATA and stripped my DOCTYPE.