# Match just the spelling and not letter case in getAttribute() - PHP

Tags: php

I have a long html and I use the php's DOMElement to parse it like this -:
`$contents` is the variable having the html

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); @$doc->loadHTML($contents);
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

`$metas` will be true only if in the html the meta tag is written like this -:

```
<meta></meta>
```

But if they are written in `uppercase` or a `combination of upper and lowercase`, it returns false

How to go about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to load XML document with DOMElements case-folded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103630/is-it-possible-to-load-xml-document-with-domelements-case-folded)

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument is meant to handle XML compliant structures and XML tags names are case-sensitive. I'm afraid you will have to parse the HTML code. As you're only looking for  tags, doesn't looks like very hard.

Another, more flexible, solution, is to pre-process *$contents* and to lowercase all tags whith some preg_replace. Something like

```
$contents = $preg_replace_callback(
'!</?\s+(\w+)]+!', 
create_function('$matches', 'return strtolower($matches[1]);'),
$contents);
```

NB : untested code, just consider it as a template and check the docs. Anyway, you've got the point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand your question right, you may create a reference of the variable. Example would be:

```
$meta = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$testMeta = strtolower($meta);
```

and compare $testMeta.